# Why does using Redis lpush and brpop in Ruby gradually leak memory?

Tags: ruby, memory, redis, garbage-collection

Running the following block of code results in the process consuming more and more memory over time:

```
require 'redis'

def rss ; `ps -o rss= -p #{Process.pid}`.chomp.to_i ; end
def gc_and_print_rss
  GC.start(full_mark: true, immediate_sweep: true)
  rss.to_s.gsub(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(\..*)?$)/,'\1,') + " kilobytes"
end

str = ('dummystring' * 1000).freeze
list_name = 'test'.freeze

r = Redis.new
r.del(list_name)

100.times do
  r.pipelined do
    10000.times do
      r.lpush(list_name, str)
    end
  end

  10000.times do
    r.brpop(list_name)
  end

  something = gc_and_print_rss
  puts something
end
```

With an output of:

```
61,288 kilobytes
82,708 kilobytes
83,640 kilobytes
83,812 kilobytes
92,228 kilobytes
93,516 kilobytes
99,848 kilobytes
99,868 kilobytes
99,872 kilobytes
99,872 kilobytes
99,876 kilobytes (5 times)
100,528 kilobytes (9 times)
100,532 kilobytes (9 times)
100,544 kilobytes
101,036 kilobytes
101,036 kilobytes
101,036 kilobytes
```

My only guess is that the `gc_and_print_rss` function is initializing a string as an hval and when enough of these strings are initialized, ruby requests another page of memory from the OS. But this begs the question, how is one to write a loop in ruby (of anything non-trivial) without creeping up in memory until the process terminates?

Tested on macOS and Ubuntu.

Comment: which process increases in memory usage Redis or Ruby?

Comment: @Kris The ruby process.

Comment: Ruby 2.4 - I get start: `47,588 kilobytes`, end `47,684 kilobytes`.

Comment: @Kris what exact versions of ruby and redis gem are you using? Can you you see if using ruby version `2.4.4` and redis client `4.0.1` result in different behavior for you?

Comment: that was with Ruby 2.4.0 and Redis::VERSION 3.3.5

Comment: with Ruby 2.4.0 and redis client 4.0.1 I end with `47,688 kilobytes`

Comment: @Kris Very strange. I start at `62,936` and climb to `80,000+` within 15 seconds. What OS are you using? I assume you are using MRI? Any ideas why this might be?

Comment: MRI on Ubuntu. Sorry, no idea.